# How should these filters work?

Tags: filter, faceted-search

I have a product page with product reviews which can be filtered. The top level filters are by review type: All, videos, product reviews and stories.

Product reviews and stories can then be filtered by subject type. How should the subject type filter work. For example if **ALL** is selected the subject filter only applies to Product reviews and stories. How do I show the filters only apply to two of the review types?

Comment: Can you give some examples of "subject types"? How many are there?

Comment: There are 3 review subject types based on rating scales the user fills out in a feedback form. "Fast acting" "Continuos benefit" and one other yet to be defined. So if the user rated the "Fast acting" as high the product review would be tagged with this term and can therefore be seen if the user wants to filter reviews by users who have said the product is "Fast acting" Hope that helps?

Comment: Are the reviews of different types (video, product reviews, stories) interleaved on the page or are they separated into groups of reviews of the same type, e.g., all videos together, all product reviews together, all stories together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea is to group the child category filters below the parent category.  This makes it clear that the child category filters will return a subset of the parent:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8tFOM.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This design gives you flexibility in the event that your taxonomy changes.  For example if a new subject type is created for Product Reviews but not videos, you could add that in without having to make any changes to the control's logic.

**Update**

The more I have thought about it, the more I dislike having "All" as an option in the UI at all.

[Marcos'](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30057/which-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-faceted-search-filtering-radio-buttons-vs) question about faceted search made a good point:

> ...most of the websites use a set of check boxes, and the All function is done by checking all the boxes, eg. Kayak or Amazon do it like this.

With only 3 review types, it is fairly simple for a user to select 1, 2, or 3 options.  As a result I'd instead use the following UI:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Dabz.png)</sup>

**Update 2** Incorporated [kountor's](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/21973/kontur) excellent suggestion of pre-checking child categories.

Comment: Great answer, the key is that it must be very clearly expressed that the subject types are related to the Product reviews and Stories only...

Comment: As an addition you can consider the following when a user clicks on "Product Reviews": Automatically also check all child-types.

Comment: Excellent point, I updated the second mockup to reflect that